# Twitter bootstrap well corner text/image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a well div, and I would like to attach a small text/image at the corner, as shown here (http://draw.to/D46BqsC)...and have that element be placed relatively to the well, so that  it changes position as the well does. What is the best approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` to make an element position itself in an absolute location relative to its parent (in this case the well).  The only catch is the parent element has to be something other than static, so your well might need to be contained in something else.

```
.my-well {
    position: relative;
}

.my-well span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

<div class="well my-well">
    <span>xxx</span>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YPcLy/